# You need to choose options for your item even if option is chosen - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, debugging, frontend-error

I get this error on all configurable products "You need to choose options for your item" when i try to add a product to cart even if size and color option are chosen

Magento 2.2.5

This error is only on product detail, in product list add to cart works fine

How can i degub?

Comment: Can we have frontend link ?

Comment: no i'm sorry it is on local host

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check what parameters we are sending in post data.when we select color and size so it select their option id and these option id sent in post data.So you need to check Post data in addProduct function.

Comment: how can i check what parameters we are sending in post data?

Comment: When u click on add to cart it always hit a controller so in that controller you have to print_r the request which you are getting from the post.

filePath: vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Cart Add.php.
Print this line: $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

Comment: @Altravista did u get post Data?

Comment: no but the strange thing is that only firefox browser have this problem but i have delete cache and also reinstall firefox

Comment: @Altravista the only reason "You need to choose options for your item" error occur when you don't post proper data to function. if its related to your browser issue then you should check the post data in different different browser and check if there any parameter is missing or not.if you get all the parameters in all browser then this issue is related to browser cache.